# How to implement "GET" request to work for STRAVA API from Postman?

Tags: api, postman, strava

Further update...

I got this working.  Although Strava's documentation does not say any of the arguments in the call are mandatory it seems they all are.  You need to put valid before and after arguments in epoch time and... (and this is the part that confused me a bit) you need to give a page number and items per page.  The items per page default to 30 but the page number does not default.  The way it works is if you say page 1 and 30 items per page you get items 1 - 30.  If you say page 3 and 30 items per page you get items 31 - 60 and so on.  You have to create a loop that keeps going until it gets a blank page.  You then know you have retrieved all the activities. (At least that is how I think it works.)

Adrian

Question update...

After some digging and experimenting I have managed to solve some of my problem (as described below) on my own.  When one creates an app on Strava listed under your settings under "My API Application" the token given has scope "read" and seems to be very, very limited.

After following the steps listed here [Strava Authentication](http://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/) I was able to get a new token with the following scopes:

scope=read,activity:read,activity:read_all,profile:read_all,read_all

So... I thought I was "golden" as the saying goes.

Well now I am able to get individual activities using:

https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/2110745394?include_all_efforts="true"&access_token={{ADR_Strava_API_Key}}

But when I try to get a list of all activities I don't get any error messages but Strava simply returns

[]  and this for an athlete that I know has over 1800 activities.

What I really want is to get the list of activities.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Adrian

I can get athlete information back from Strava using postman using the following https request:

https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/19133707?access_token={{ADR_Strava_API_Key}}

The following gets returned:

```
{
    "id": 19133707,
    "username": "adrian_geekie",
    "resource_state": 2,
    "firstname": "Adrian",
    "lastname": "Geekie",
    "city": "Gauteng, South Africa",
    "state": "GP",
    "country": "South Africa",
    "sex": "M",
    "premium": true,
    "summit": true,
    "created_at": "2017-01-03T16:07:37Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-01-28T16:08:07Z",
    "badge_type_id": 1,
    "profile_medium": "https://dgalywyr863hv.cloudfront.net/pictures/athletes/19133707/5599004/2/medium.jpg",
    "profile": "https://dgalywyr863hv.cloudfront.net/pictures/athletes/19133707/5599004/2/large.jpg",
    "friend": null,
    "follower": null
}
```

But when I try to get activities using this request:

https://www.strava.com/api/v3/19133707/activities?before=&after=1546293601&page=&per_page=&access_token={{ADR_Strava_API_Key}}

I get this returned:

{
    "message": "Record Not Found",
    "errors": [
        {
            "resource": "resource",
            "field": "path",
            "code": "invalid"
        }
    ]
}

According to me I am asking for all records after the 1st of January 2019 i.e. epoch timestamp 1546293601.  I know there are many activities for that athlete after that date. (More than 20).

I have also tried to get a single activity using:

https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/2110745394?include_all_efforts="true"&access_token={{ADR_Strava_API_Key}}

and I get the result:

{
    "message": "Resource Not Found",
    "errors": [
        {
            "resource": "Activity",
            "field": "",
            "code": "not found"
        }
    ]
}

On the Strava developer's page the examples are given for HTTPie like this:

https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/{id}?include_all_efforts=" "Authorization: Bearer [[token]]

So I am replacing "Authorization: Bearer [[token]] with &access_token=

Perhaps that is my error but access_token works in the first example.

I am sorry if this is a total idiot question.  I am a beginner and I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: On october 15, 2018 Strava enhanched the authorization process introducing new list of scopes; give a look here, maybe your actual scope is not enought to read activities: https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: @Adrian J G - were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: Yes @Bryce I was.  I described what I did above.  If you have a specific question I can try to assist.